# Confused how to support array with xbase

Tags: xtext, xbase

**I want can use array normally like: a[1].**
The xbase seems not support array grammar, so i defined this myself.
But this task overcome my head.
Thanks.

error(211): ../org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel/src-gen/org/eclipse/xtext/example/domainmodel/parser/antlr/internal/InternalDomainmodel.g:576:2: [fatal] rule ruleXExpressionOrVarDeclaration has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 2,3.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.

```
generate domainmodel "http://www.xtext.org/example/Domainmodel"
import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase" as xbase

DomainModel:
    importSection=XImportSection?
    elements+=AbstractElement*;

AbstractElement:
    PackageDeclaration | Entity;

PackageDeclaration:
    'package' name=QualifiedName '{'
        elements+=AbstractElement*
    '}';

Entity:
    'script' name=ValidID ('extends' superType=JvmParameterizedTypeReference)? '{'
        features+=Feature*
    '}';

Feature:
    Property | Operation;

Property:
    name=ValidID ':' type=JvmTypeReference;

Operation:
    'def' name=ValidID '(' (params+=FullJvmFormalParameter (',' params+=FullJvmFormalParameter)*)? ')' (':' type=JvmTypeReference)?
        body=XBlockExpression;

@Override 
XExpressionOrVarDeclaration returns xbase::XExpression:
    XVariableDeclaration | NpExpression | XExpression;

NpExpression returns xbase::XExpression:
     XExpression '[' INT ']'
;

NpSlice:
    {IntConstant} value=INT
;
```

Comment: NpExpression returns xbase::XExpression:
 {NpExpression} QualifiedName (=>'[' INT ']')
;warning(200): ../org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel/src-gen/org/eclipse/xtext/example/domainmodel/parser/antlr/internal/InternalDomainmodel.g:576:2: Decision can match input such as "RULE_ID '.' RULE_ID '[' RULE_INT ']'" using multiple alternatives: 2, 3

Comment: I'm not an expert on Xtext, but Xtext uses Antlr3. Antlr3 does not handle any form of left recursion. Antlr4, which has been out for 8+ years, handles direct-left recursion, but not indirect-left recursion. It looks like you need to rewrite the rules for NpExpression, XExpression, XExpressionOrVarDeclaration. But, it is hard to say without seeing all of InternalDomainmodel.g.

Comment: Still not work, maybe xbase too complex. NJBlockExpression returns xbase::XExpression:
 {NJExpression} 
 '{'
  (expressions+=NPExpression ';'?)*
 '}';

@Override 
XCastedExpression returns xbase::XExpression:
 NPExpression (=>({XCastedExpression.target=current} 'as') type=JvmTypeReference)*
;

NPExpression returns xbase::XExpression:
 NPArrayCall =>({XPostfixOperation.operand=current} feature=[types::JvmIdentifiableElement|OpPostfix])?
;

NPArrayCall returns xbase::XExpression:
 XMemberFeatureCall => ({Array.left = current} '[' index=INT ']')*
;